# Pulling Stylesheet src/href from an external file, JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have an html source and I know the URL, "example_url.html". This html file has a <`link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`.

This is an iframe's src I am using in another view, and I want to pull the stylesheet listed in "example_url.html". How do I go about that?

And I don't know the actual href of stylesheet, and it changes based on various factors (but everything shares a domain name). I'll need it as a variable.

Comment: So accessing CSS of parent document inside an iframe?

Comment: Can you not get it using Firebug?

Comment: Have you tried `example_url.html/style.css`?

Comment: I don't know the actual stylesheet's href, "style.css" is just an example. It's much more complicated and it changes based on various things.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what CSS of parent document means, but I am in "index.html" which loads iframe with the src "example.html", and "example.html" has the stylesheet "style.css". So the page I'm currently on doesn't have "style.css" in it's source. Sorry if this is confusing. *googling Firebug*

Comment: I don't think I can use Firebug for what I'm doing.

Comment: is the example_url.html and the js trying to get the css on the same site? otherwise I don't think you'll be able to get it using js due to cross domain restrictions

Comment: Yes it's from the same domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you give the iframe an ID, I think something like this should work:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("the-iframe-id");
var child_doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var child_links = child_doc.getElementsByTagName("link");
var child_css;
for (var i = 0; i < child_links.length; i++) {
  if (child_links[i].rel == "stylesheet") {
      child_css = child_links[i].href;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm this seems like it should work. I grab the iframe successfully, but then child_doc returns (null || undefined) for those two possible assignments. It does have the src set though.

Comment: Oh you know what. I am being so silly. I apologize. Normally this does have the same domain, but I"m on local host. Duh. I bet this will work otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's the cross-domain failure.